# Add JBP_CONFIG option to scdf task

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcf

I've updated the java version in my application and now receiving the following error

```
[ERR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/spatial/batch/BatchApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I added `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{jre: { version: 11.+ }}'` to fix this problem and it's helped. Now I want to do the same with scdf task. I've tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work

```
spring:
  cloud:
    deployer:
      cloudfoundry:
        domain: ****
        freeDiskSpacePercentage: 15
        org: ****
        password: "****"
        space: ****
        url: "****"
        username: ****
        api-timeout: 360
        javaOpts: -Xms512m -Xmx768m
        skip:
          ssl:
            validation: false
        stream:
          buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
          services: "p-rbt"
        task:
          buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
          services: "config-server,config-server-keystore,p-rbt,logstash-syslog,elastic-apm"
          disk: 4096
          memory: 4096
          taskTimeout: 540
          health:
            check: none
          env:
            JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{jre: { version: 11.+ }}'
```

What is the right way to set environment variables into scdf task?

Answer (score 0):

The location of env is not correct.
It should be still under the manifest file. But not the application yaml.
env:
JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{jre: { version: 11.+ }}'